# How can I preload the blob of a has_one_attached variant_record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm using Rails 7.0.3.1 with ActiveStorage.

I have a

```
class Element < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image do |blob|
    blob.variant :large, { resize_to_fill: [744, 387], saver: { quality: 70 } }
    blob.variant :medium, { resize_to_fill: [558, 290], saver: { quality: 70 } }
    blob.variant :small, { resize_to_fill: [372, 194], saver: { quality: 70 } }
  end
end
```

In my template I want to render a `picture` tag with a `srcset` attribute with different resolutions like so (using haml):

```
.element__image-wrapper
  %picture
    = image_tag @element.image.variant(:large).processed.url, width: 744, height: 387, |
      srcset: "#{@element.image.variant(:large).processed.url} 744w, |
      #{@element.image.variant(:medium).processed.url} 558w, |
      #{@element.image.variant(:small).processed.url} 372w"
```

This works fine, but I am not able to do this without N+1 db queries

I can do this:

```
> element = Element.first
  Element Load
=> #<Element:0x00007fde115ee038
...
> element.image.variant_records.load
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load
  ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load
=> [#<ActiveStorage::VariantRecord:0x00007fddf2c30ff0 id: 1, blob_id: 1, variation_digest: "fayCsCJnE0tYtxSs06wT4zzkL9M=">,                                                    
...
> element.image.variant_records.loaded?
=> true
> element.image.variant(:large).processed?
=> true
> element.image.variant(:large).image.blob
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load
=> #<ActiveStorage::Blob:0x00007fddf31d1270
...
```

How can I preload the `image_attachment: :blob` of the `variant_records`?

I already tried

```
> element.reload
  Element Load
=> #<Element:0x00007fde115ee038
> element.image.variant_records.preload(image_attachment: :blob)
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load
  ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load
=> [#<ActiveStorage::VariantRecord:0x00007fddf2c30ff0 id: 1, blob_id: 1, variation_digest: "fayCsCJnE0tYtxSs06wT4zzkL9M=">,
```

And this seems to work (the 4th and 5th queries are the right ones), but when I then access the variant, it gets loaded again:

```
> element.image.variant_records.loaded?
=> false
> element.image.variant(:large).processed?
  ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load
=> true
> element.image.variant(:large).image.blob
  ActiveStorage::VariantRecord Load
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load
=> #<ActiveStorage::Blob:0x00007fde100c2650
```

Is it possible to get all data needed with 5 queries?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this one?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Do you have the same problem, @rogerkk?

Comment: Indeed I do. Haven't had the time to really dig into it yet, and was hoping someone else had solved it for me. 

Answer (score 1):

You can preload blob variants with an includes :

For example with `has_many_attached :photos` in the MyModel model, you

```rb
MyModel.includes(photos_attachments: [blob: [variant_records: {image_attachment: :blob}]])
```